# Autolayout on button and textfield in ios

Tags: uibutton, autolayout, uitextfield, image-resizing

I have made simple login form containing buttons , image and textfields. i am trying to have same layout for all iphone screens . i tried using autolayout to give same space all around the view but its not providing the required results . here is the screen shot of an unwanted result (there should be an equal amount of space on bottom of "Forget password text"):
[image]

Comment: ur problm got solved or not

Comment: NO .if you have found any better solution then plz share it

Answer (score 0):

you should give fixed bottom space to superView(forget password) constraint  higher priority then  top spacing constraint b/w forget password and sign_in.

**EDIT**
give a try
1.fixed bottom spacing b/w forget password and superview and fixed top spacing b/w forget password and sign in 
2. the spacing between sign in and password textfield must be less than or equal , so that if phone size decrease it will shrink not other constraint.

Comment: yes ...but i think space between username and password should also be shrinked ...how can i achieve this ?

Comment: @warzone_fz if you just want to change that constraint spacing b/w these two textField , then make a IBOutlet of that constraint and give it a value of your need.. (self.outlet.constant = value) .

Comment: any idea how we can get this using IB/